# PRIOR ART REQUEST: US20150066784 "Automated Clickwrap and Browsewrap System"

Tags: prior-art-request, us20150066784

I would like some help finding prior art for [US20150066784](https://ppubs.uspto.gov/pubwebapp/static/pages/landing.html).

The patent describes a system focused on the browsewrap vs. clickwrap distinction when it comes to legal agreements, but the entire system seems like a industry best practice.

I view that the clickwrap implementation (a checkbox with the "I Agree" text) to make sure the user agrees to an agreement has already been best practice for a while now, popularized more and more since the [Zappos lawsuit](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ericgoldman/2012/10/10/how-zappos-user-agreement-failed-in-court-and-left-zappos-legally-naked/).

Even a system of tracking users to keep track who agreed to certain agreements has been best practice, though not popularized as much.

I currently found 2 examples of prior art, but it would be great to see if more prior art exists.

**Examples of prior art (especially for for 1st and 6th claims):**

*1. A method for monitoring end-user viewing of agreements over a computer network*

*6. A method for monitoring end-user affirmative consent to agreements over a computer network*

Hasn't this be already done by the [Agreeable Records plugin for WordPress](https://web.archive.org/web/20160118121542/http://kraftpress.it/downloads/agreeable-records/), first launched in [Jan 2014](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/log/agreeable?rev=1133899) ?

```
Need to track when a user logs in and agrees to your terms? Agreeable Records tracks     
the user’s email and IP address with every login agreement, allowing you to keep 
detailed records of a user’s agreement to your terms & conditions. Requires Agreeable 
plugin.
```

The plugin is specifically built for this, but many other form plugins for WordPress allow developers to add the "I Agree" checkbox on their web forms:

- the Contact Form 7 plugin and its ability to add checkbox for agreements acceptance, [first mentioned in 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20170725124951/http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com:80/agree-to-terms).

PrivacyCheq and [its Cliqwrap](https://www.privacycheq.com/?page_id=35805) system is being described similarly:

```
CliqWrap stores user acceptance of your TOS / EULA, allowing new games to bypass 
requesting duplicate approvals. When your legal agreements change, one button resets 
approvals so all users will see the new terms at next login.
```

[image: image of PrivacyCheq]

The [WP E-Signature](https://www.approveme.com/) plugin for WordPress seems similar to this (a public mention of launch was in [May 2014](https://www.checkbca.org/report/approveme-esignature--digital-e-signature-for-wordpress-155652277), but the domain name was registered in 2010), including tracking users who agreed to specific agreements, but users agree to the agreement via their e-signature:

[image: image for WP E-Signature]
<sub>(source: [approveme.me](https://www.approveme.me/wp-content/themes/marketify-child/img/home-c/home/wordpress-electronic-signature-hero.jpg))</sub>

Comment: one need to also check out if agreements are user specific.

Comment: @Pushpak Could something like [WP Digital e-Signature](https://www.approveme.me/wp-digital-signature-plugin-docs/article/wp-digital-e-signature-active-campaign-email-automation/) be considered prior art in regards to this? It's more focused on e-signature, but the web forms are still implemented using clickwrap implementation and they agree to a specific agreement (NDA, etc.)

Comment: In order to get the best help from the community, it would help to have a date so that we know when "prior" is.

Comment: @McKay Good point, thanks. Updated with what I could find.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the goal behind finding prior art for this patent?

Comment: Can we all agree not to call applications patents? This is an application, not a patent. It may never become a patent and if it does, its claims are likely to change. I'm all for finding prior art for over broad applications, but using the term patent confuses people.

Comment: The application got a non final rejection, the claims will probably be narrowed in the response.

Answer (score 1):

I found this, it's called [End User License Agreement Detection and Monitoring](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130185807), this is what the abstract says:

> "An approach is provided for detecting and monitoring end user license
>   agreement (EULA) compliance is provided. A request to access a
>   executable software code is received from an end user. A EULA version
>   corresponding to the requested executable software code is identified.
>   A determination is made as to whether the end user has accepted the
>   identified EULA. If the end user has not accepted the identified EULA,
>   then an out of date EULA notification is sent to the end user, the
>   EULA is sent to the end user requesting an acceptance to the EULA. A
>   EULA response is received from the end user. If the end user accepts
>   the EULA, then the end user is allowed access to the executable
>   software code."

hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Browsewrap Agreements: Register.com, Inc. v. Verio, Inc.; Tracy, James J.](http://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/jstl11&div=11&id=&page=)

Not an expert in electronic but Seems to be listing most of the contents with inference and observations. Probably teaching the same.

[Are Browse-Wrap Agreements All They Are Wrapped Up To Be?](http://kfmlaw.com/library/browsewrapabstract.pdf)